# Cheking uniqueness of key values in java properties files

Tags: java, properties

I want to load a certain number of properties files into the same java.util.Properties object. I achieve this correctly with the following code:

```
public class GloalPropReader {

public static final Properties DISPATCHER = new Properties();
public static final Properties GLOBAL_PROP = new Properties();

public GloalPropReader() {
    try (InputStream input = GloalPropReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dispatcher.properties")) {
        DISPATCHER.load(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't access dispatcher information");
    }

    for (Object nth : DISPATCHER.keySet()) {
        String nthKey = (String) nth;
        String nthPathToOtherProps = (String) DISPATCHER.get(nthKey);
        Path p = Paths.get(nthPathToOtherProps);
        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(p.toFile())) {
            GLOBAL_PROP.load(input);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't access " + nthPathToOtherProps + " information");
        }
    }
}
```

}

And having this properties files:

**dispatcher.properties**

```
path_to_prop_1=C:/Users/U/Desktop/k.properties
path_to_prop_2=C:/Users/U/Desktop/y.properties
```

**k.properties**

```
prop1=BLABLA
```

**y.properties**

```
prop2=BLEBLE
```

But what i would like to achieve is to throw a RuntimeException if 2 properties file have the same key inside. For instance, **i would like this class to throw an exception if k.properties and y.properties were so**:

**k.properties**

```
prop1=BLABLA
```

**y.properties**

```
prop1=BLEBLE
```

**EDIT**

It's the same as this post [Loading multiple properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181239/loading-multiple-properties-files) but i don't want the overriding logic when 2 keys are equal

Comment: Why? It is easy to arrange them so that one overrides the other if they are both present.

Comment: I don't want someone to ovveride them... Probably overriding it is an error, an might result in a funky not understandable behaviour of the software

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class GloalPropReader {
    private final Properties K_PROPERTIES = new Properties();
    private final Properties Y_PROPERTIES = new Properties();

    public GloalPropReader() {
        loadProperties("k.properties", K_PROPERTIES);

        loadProperties("y.properties", Y_PROPERTIES);

        Set intersection = new HashSet(K_PROPERTIES.keySet());
        intersection.retainAll(Y_PROPERTIES.keySet());
        if (!intersection.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Property intersection detected " + intersection);
        }
    }

    private void loadProperties(String name, Properties y_properties) {
        try (InputStream input = GloalPropReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)) {
            y_properties.load(input);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't access dispatcher information");
        }
    }
}
```